# How to remove dups in list with groupby in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Have a large data file where I need to remove the dups across the row. I used groupby to group on the ID and then add the values across the 12 columns into a list. The last step I need is to remove if there a duplicate values in the list.

I know set() will remove the dups in a traditional list but I'm not sure if that will work in my groupby or if there is a better way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")

grouped = df.groupby('<ID>')['fb1','fb2','fb3'].apply(lambda 
x: x.values.tolist())
```

**Currently, where you can see the dup "Includes Handle"**

us_7493577     [[Nonspillable Battery., Can Be Shipped By Air...

us_7493578     [[Nonspillable Battery., Can Be Shipped By Air...

us_7493586             [[Includes Handle, Includes Handle, nan]]

**The result I am looking for**

us_7493577     [[Nonspillable Battery., Can Be Shipped By Air...

us_7493578     [[Nonspillable Battery., Can Be Shipped By Air...

us_7493586             [[Includes Handle, nan]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `set`s in lambda function and set comprehension:

```
f = lambda x: set([z for y in x.values for z in y])
grouped = df.groupby('<ID>')['fb1','fb2','fb3'].apply(f)
```

If need also remove missing values filter them by comparing `z == z`, because `np.nan != np.nan` - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

```
f = lambda x: set([z for y in x.values for z in y if z == z])
grouped = df.groupby('<ID>')['fb1','fb2','fb3'].apply(f)
```

Comment: I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' now

Comment: I appreciate the help. I applied the changes and got a weird result.

Comment: us_7441859     {c, g, 2, 3, f, b, _, 1, p}
us_7481710     {c, g, 2, 3, f, b, _, 1, p}
us_7481711     {c, g, 2, 3, f, b, _, 1, p}
us_7481712     {c, g, 2, 3, f, b, _, 1, p}

Comment: @Sam - oops, missing `.values`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael this works good enough. Something interesting if the dropna() is in the code it looks like the result completely removes dup values and doesn't leave one. Just if there are dups it wipes it all out. But if I remove this portion it does what I need by combining the dups to one value, but I am left with nan.